# Is there anyway to load data and labels separately using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a classification problem and I have a pile of images stored in two directories:

`my_data/Total/M0`

`my_data/Total/B0`

where M0 is a sub-directory for one class and B0 is for another class.

when I use:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  train_dir,
  validation_split=0.1,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=30336)
```

it returns batch of tuples with first element being the data and the second element the label
I was wondering if there is anyway to load these data so that the data and labels are separated like:

`x_train , y_train = ...`

Comment: What do you mean by “data and labels are separated”? What is your expected result?

Comment: basically I want my images in a 4D tensor [batch, width, height, dim] and the corresponding labels in a separate tensor.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, `train_ds` should produce the desired output.

Check out this code:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    validation_split=0.1,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(300, 300), # Note that I changed the image size to (300, 300)
    batch_size=30 # Note that I changed the batch size to 30
)

for x, y in train_ds:
    print(x.shape)
    break
```

This would output `(30, 300, 300, 3)` which should match your desired shape of `(batch, width, height, dim)`.